# Is there a way let the Spark Streaming Application quit when a Job aborted

Tags: apache-spark

I have submitted a spark Streaming application to the Yarn.
When one job executes failed. The following jobs continue to execute.
Is there a way when one job execute failed, the whole application exits?

As in my case, the data should be processed in sequence, we should not skip any data. If we found any error, we need to stop the application and do troubleshooting instead of continuing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first, we have to make sure spark streaming stops gracefully, for that set spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown parameter to be true (default is false)

Then you can throw an exception from code responsible for failure and bubble it up to the main / driver, surrounding the main body in a try catch and from inside the catch you can call ssc.stop(true, true).

Another way is - from inside catch block wrapping  the code responsible for failure create a marker file in persistent storage ( hdfs or s3 or whatever spark is associated with) and keep checking that from driver - whenever the marker file is present delete it as well as call ssc.stop(true, true).

An example can be found at
https://github.com/lanjiang/streamingstopgraceful/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/cloudera/ps/GracefulShutdownExample.scala

Comment: Many Thanks, We could not throw the exception to the driver as the exception is on the executor. I believe the second way can solve this problem. Currently, our solution extends the StreamingListener, while a new batch starts, it will check if there are already another active batch running, if another active batch is running, the streaming listener will notify the stop.  BTW, is there any documents describing that the Spark will continue even when some jobs failed. Even it seems to be a normal sense, but I could not find any official documents about it.

Comment: Are you looking for a document that will tell you "Why" the Spark will continue even when some jobs failed?

Comment: Yes. I am using the [spark-streaming-kafka](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-8-integration.html), and I found when one job failed(Exceptions were throw out in the RDD), another job started with a new offset. While the failed job still shows as processing on the Spark UI. In this case, I also could not understand why the Spark UI shows the failed Jobs as processing?